# How can I show the tooltips giving the element dimensions?

Tags: google-chrome-devtools

In Chrome Developer Tools I get the pink-blue-pink highlighting but I don't see the handy yellow tooltips with the element dimensions. I tried toggling basically all options but it's still not showing. How can I get it?

[image]

Comment: Same question -unanswered - [here](http://productforums.google.com/forum/#!topic/chrome/jl8hKZ-9V0U).